# MvvmCross - how to bind to SelectedItem in iOS TableView?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross, xamarin-binding

I have a TableView in iOS and, in my ViewModel, I have a property to Selected Item in TableView, but I don't know how to bind the Selected Item for this property. How can I do that? My project is cross-platform. I have an Android project and an iOS project. In Android project, I did the bind:

```
<Mvx.MvxListView
                    android:id="@+id/lstViewTasks"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                    android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"
                    local:MvxBind="ItemsSource Tasks; SelectedItem SelectedTask; ItemClick ShowTaskCommand"
                    local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/projectmytasksitem" />
```

but I can't do a equivalent bind in iOS.

That's my TableViewController:

```
[Register("ProjectMyTasksViewc")]
public class ProjectMyTasksViews : MvxTableViewController<ProjectMyTasksViewModel>
{
        //other things

        var source = new MvxSimpleTableViewSource(TableView, ProjectMyTasksItem.Key, ProjectMyTasksItem.Key);
        TableView.Source = source;

        this.CreateBinding(source).To<ProjectMyTasksViewModel>(viewModel => viewModel.Tasks).Apply();
        this.CreateBinding(source).For(s => s.SelectedItem).To<ProjectMyTasksViewModel>(viewModel => viewModel.SelectedTask).Apply();
        this.CreateBinding(source).For(tableSource => tableSource.SelectionChangedCommand).To<ProjectMyTasksViewModel>(viewModel => viewModel.ShowTaskCommand).Apply();

}
```

Here is my ViewModel:

```
public class ProjectMyTasksViewModel : MvxViewModel
{

public Action ShowTaskCommandAction { get; set; }

private IList<Task> _tasks;
public IList<Task> Tasks
{
    get { return _tasks; }
    set { _tasks = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => Tasks); }
}

private Task _selectedTask;
public Task SelectedTask
{
    get { return _selectedTask; }
    set { _selectedTask = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => SelectedTask); }
}

private MvxCommand _showTaskCommand;
public MvxCommand ShowTaskCommand
{
    get
    {
        _showTaskCommand = _showTaskCommand ?? (_showTaskCommand = new MvxCommand(ExecuteShowTaskCommand));
        return _showTaskCommand;
    }
}

private void ExecuteShowTaskCommand()
{
    if (!SelectedTask.IsCompleted)
    {
        ShowTaskCommandAction?.Invoke();
    }
}  
}
```

Comment: What issue are you experiencing with `SelectedItem` binding? Any compile or runtime errors? Or is `SelectedTask` set just getting hit?

Comment: I'm had a NullReferenceException. The property SelectedTask in ViewModel is null.

Comment: Could you please include the part of your ViewModel with `SelectedItem`, `ShowTaskCommand` and where the NullReferenceExcepti‌on occurs?

Comment: I edited the ask. I put the ViewModel code. The NullReferenceException occurs at the ExecuteShowTaskCommand method in the line if (!SelectedTask.IsCompleted). At this point, the SelectedTask is null.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it has to do with the timing of your `ShowTaskCommand` getting executed vs the set of `SelectedTask`. So if you commented out the code inside `ExecuteShowTaskCommand` and place a breakpoint inside `ExecuteShowTaskCommand` as well as the set of `SelectedTask` you would find that the `ExecuteShowTaskCommand` is running first and then the set of the `SelectedTask`.

---

**Alternative implementation**

To avoid the timing issue you can instead pass the selected task into your command as a parameter.

```
MvxCommand<Task> _showTaskCommand;
public MvxCommand<Task> ShowTaskCommand =>
    _showTaskCommand ?? (_showTaskCommand = new MvxCommand<Task>(ExecuteShowTaskCommand));

private void ExecuteShowTaskCommand(Task selectedTask)
{
    if (!selectedTask.IsCompleted)
    {
        ShowTaskCommandAction?.Invoke();
    }
}
```